# How to convert a python script .py file into an exe without embedding python interpreter in it

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, py2exe

My requirement is to deploy a python script in a form of exe with digital signature but the python interpreter and dependent python modules should not be embedded into the exe. Rather, python needs to be explicitly installed on the server.
I have tried pyinstaller and cx_freeze but both embeds python and related modules along with the script codebase into the exe. We need to decouple python and script codebase.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to create a Windows *.exe file which is a PE executable that contains a Python script and which, upon launch, finds an installed Python runtime and uses it to run the embedded script?

Comment: If you are installing python on the machine you're running your code, why it should need to be an .exe? Could packaging to a wheel be enough?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes. That's correct

Comment: @np8 I wanted to perform code signing on my python files to ensure the scripts has not been modified by anyone on the server. But  could not find a mechanism for same so thought of converting py into exe and then sign it using Microsoft signtool.exe.

Comment: @np8 Packaging into wheel won't help as again I cannot perform code signing on wheel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)  and use [Cython](http://cython.org/) to convert your key .py files in .pyc, C compiled files, like .dll in Windows and .so on Linux.

Alternatively, you can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to package Python programs as standalone executables. It works on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: Executables generated from PyInstaller embeds Python interpreter along with source code. I don't want it as Python needs to be installed separately.